# Reorder li's by time order of time within the li in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-lists

I have some sales data which is loaded into a ul by ajax with an id of ajaxInner. Unfortunately these li's are not appended in time order. How do I create a JavaScript function to sort these li's into time order by the time in the transactTime span. I would like this as a function I can call after each new li is appended so it takes account of all the li's in the list and reorders them accordingly by the time.

```
<ul id="ajaxInner">
    <li><span class="transactTime">10:13 - </span><span class="transactAmount">£444</span><br><img src="images/orangeMarker.png" class="mapMarker"><span class="transactCity">Stoke-on-trent (Stoke-On-Trent, United Kingdom)</span></li>
    <li><span class="transactTime">10:08 - </span><span class="transactAmount">£56</span><br><img src="images/orangeMarker.png" class="mapMarker"><span class="transactCity">Belper (Derbyshire, United Kingdom)</span></li>
    <li><span class="transactTime">10:15 - </span><span class="transactAmount">£39</span><br><img src="images/orangeMarker.png" class="mapMarker"><span class="transactCity">Stoke-on-trent (Stoke-On-Trent, United Kingdom)</span></li>
    <li><span class="transactTime">10:14 - </span><span class="transactAmount">£459</span><br><img src="images/orangeMarker.png" class="mapMarker"><span class="transactCity">Belper (Derbyshire, United Kingdom)</span></li>
    <li><span class="transactTime">10:16 - </span><span class="transactAmount">£1057</span><br><img src="images/orangeMarker.png" class="mapMarker"><span class="transactCity">Scarborough (North Yorkshire, United Kingdom)</span></li>
    <li><span class="transactTime">10:11 - </span><span class="transactAmount">£107</span><br><img src="images/orangeMarker.png" class="mapMarker"><span class="transactCity">Scarborough (North Yorkshire, United Kingdom)</span></li>
</ul>
```

Code I've tried so far:

```
//sort the li's into time order
function sortList() {

    var ul = $('#ajaxInner');
    var li = ul.children("li");

    li.detach().sort();
    ul.append(li);

}
```

However this doesn't always sort by time order and you get some odd results with times at the top which shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
function sortList() {
    var ul = $('#ajaxInner');
    var li = ul.children("li");

    li.detach().sort(function(a, b) {
        var date1 = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + $(a).children('span.transactTime').text().substr(0,5))
        var date2 = new Date (new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + $(b).children('span.transactTime').text().substr(0,5))
        var result = (date1 < date2) ? -1 : (date1 > date2) ? 1 : 0
        return result;
    });

    ul.append(li);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/4Q6Xg/10/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm still seeing some weird results for this code where 11:01 will be put above 11:06 for example.

Comment: @BenPaton Or could you update the example fiddle with a case that isn't working and explain exactly what is wrong

Comment: I have copied some li's after sorting to here from test environment  http://pastebin.com/tm0miaw5 as you can see for some reason it sorted to 11:41 then 11:39 then 11:41...

Comment: Here is some more here where it has gone out of sync. http://pastebin.com/CqxmLBPS Perhaps it's to do with the way the ajax call adds new li's in?

Comment: Ok I have updated the fiddle with the ul data from the second pastbin. http://jsfiddle.net/4Q6Xg/4/ when you run this you can see the li's are not sorted by time order

Comment: These seems to work, I need to reverse the order they are appended back into the ul so the most recent time is at the top. How do I do this?

Comment: I reversed the greater than and less than signs. All seems to be working as I need. Thanks for your help with this! :)

Comment: Sorry, was on lunch!  Glad I could help